# Check if username exists in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok so have this code, its for a registration form but i can't get it to check if there is already the username taken? all it does is creates the same username in the database again, instead of returning "Username already taken" if anyone could help would be very appreciated.

```
$checkusernametaken = mysql_query("SELECT FROM users (username) WHERE username=username");
 if(mysql_num_rows($checkusernametaken)>=1)
    {
        echo"Username already exists";
    }
 else
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES(:username, :password)";
        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->execute();
        return "Registration Successful Welcome " + $checkusernametaken + "<br/> <a href='index.php'>Login Now</a>";
    }
```

This is the code i used and i got it working with the help of everyone in the comments, thanks heaps guys!

```
try {
        $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES(:username, :password)";

        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->execute();
        return "Registration Successful <br/> <a href='index.php'>Login Now</a>";
    }
    catch( PDOException $e ) 
    {
         return "Username Taken <br/> <a href='register.php'>Try Again?</a>";
    }
```

Comment: 1. You need to have an unique index for `username` column. 2. You need to check if the `INSERT` query has performed successfully.

Comment: PS: please explain what this part of your query means: `WHERE username=username`

Comment: PPS: `SELECT FROM` --- what's this? Have a look on `mysql_error` function and check if you have some errors in your queries.

Comment: Since username would be string, you have to wrap it in quotes like `username = 'username'` Also, are you using MySQL or MySQLi? Seems to me that you are mixing both MySQL and MySQLi

Comment: I don't know i have been trying everything to get it to work i found "SELECT FROM users (username) WHERE username=username" off someone elses fixes and apparently it worked for them but i cannot get it to work for me

Comment: Isn't the SELECT query incorrect? Shouldn't it be `SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='username'`

Comment: didn't work, it just registered the username

Comment: ill give that a go Patrick Lorio

Comment: it still registered the username again

Comment: @Patrick Lorio: even `SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM ...`

Comment: @Terrii: so did you just copy paste advices? Where does the input username comes from to the query?

Comment: this is the box you use to enter the username,    <input type="text" id="usn" maxlength="30" required autofocus name="username" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how the table would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
`username` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`password` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
);
```

[Live DEMO.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6cb94/1/0)

The simplest way would be if you change your table to make the field username unique, this way if you try to insert the same username it will result on a duplicate entry error which you can easily catch like this:

```
try
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES(:username, :password)";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue("username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue("password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    return "Registration Successful Welcome {$checkusernametaken}<br/><a href=\"index.php\">Login Now</a>";
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    if ($e->getCode() == 1062)
    {
        return "The selected username is not available...";
    }
    else
    {
        // More info at: http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php
        return "Handle any other errors here.";
    }
}
```

Comment: @zerkms this is the same as checking first.

Comment: @JAL: from result perspective - it is. From performance - checking with `SELECT` first is much more efficient.

Comment: @zerkms well I would say that really depends on what you want to do, in some cases you might want to check first instead of trying to insert directly, also if you want to look from a performance perspective if you have to SELECT AND INSERT on cases where the username is available then you wont have any performance at all against just catching the error

Comment: @Prix: In any case if you know what "performance" term means and if you care of it.

Comment: @Prix: "then you wont have any performance at all against just catching the erro" on duplicate username only lightweight `SELECT` will be performed. So there *is* difference.

Comment: @zerkms on the other hand you will get the overhead when the username is available as it will perform the select and the insert so I guess that is arguable.

Comment: this is the code im using, http://forum.codecall.net/topic/69771-creating-a-simple-yet-secured-loginregistration-with-php5/

Comment: sure did could you please 1 up?

Answer (score 0):

```
$checkusernametaken = mysql_query("SELECT FROM users (username) WHERE username=username");
```

here you should change to

```
$checkusernametaken = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE lcase(`username`) = lcase('".mysql_escape_string($this->username)."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it still registered the user again.

Comment: @Terrii: have you even a single idea how to program? )))

Comment: @Terrii check updated, it should work if you copy it properly

Comment: haha yeah well i'm new to php just learning how to code it :S i have never used it i have only used javascript, html, css

Comment: im getting this, Access denied for user 'enslaved'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: @Terrii so, in your code this query wasn't executed at all, as you havent established connection to mysql, check other answers - they will help

Comment: thats what im thinking but then when it registers the username is connects to the database fine but not when it needs to check :S

Comment: @Terrii tip, using PDO and the old deprecated MySQL library will not work if u don't have a connection for it, you're trying to use 2 different libraries to use MySQL where only one have a connection available and set.

Comment: so how do i connect it? i tried this:
$connecttoserver = $con->prepare( $checkusernametaken );
$connecttoserver->execute();

Comment: i have it keeps sending me to a blank page and not putting anything in the database